# What should I do if I wrote an algorithm faster than the Sieve of Atkin?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, programming

I have been having fun with prime numbers. I sat down and, following a hunch and after a few weeks of headbanging against the wall, I was able to write an algorithm that, at least on my local, provides better results than the Sieve of Atkin (at least, faster than the implementation that I found to test against).

Right now it's written on java but I will probably sit down during the weekend to translate it into C to measure it up against Atkin there as well.

In case you want to give it a test-drive:

https://github.com/eantoranz/patternsieve

Master only holds 2 classes:
- the "reference" implementation of the algorithm (which is much slower than Atkin, by the way)
- the version that I ended up having after steroids (but which holds the same concept as the reference implementation at its heart)

Then there's the 'compare' branch where I wrote a couple of additional java classes that can be used to easily and readily run tests plus an implementation of Eratosthenes and Sieve of Atkin (credits provided in commits and in code... and in output when using the classes).

What would be the best steps to follow so that people knows about it and give it a round of tests? Just writing about it over here should be enough to get people to notice it? Perhaps I should mail someone in the math community? I'm kind of a rookie in terms of "how to do and publish research".

**PS** By the way.... what do I mean with **"faster"**? I think overall it can provide some 30% faster results (but it varies a lot because of the way that the algorithm works so it can be very close to Atkin or provide more than 50% better results... depending on how many primes are being searched).

I just hope I don't get a lot of negative votes and perhaps get some people interested.

Comment: "What would be the best steps to follow so that people knows about it" Probably go to matheducator or computerscience or academia ? Not sure if it is ontopic here.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Is there a way to copy the question over? Or should I delete this one and create a new one there?

Comment: The Sieve of Atkin is not famous for its speed in *practice* but for its theoretical performance for very, very large $N$.  Unless you are reporting results for very, very large $N$, or have a formal proof of correctness and asymptotic complexity better than Atkin, I don’t see why that should be the benchmark for comparison.  You might want to compare against wheel sieve, which seems similar in principle.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but, um... what is the largest integer that this program could go up to?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. The current implementation: I have been running my tests for numbers up to 1e9, I think. The array that I'm using to hold the values has a fixed limited length so it might have to be held in 2^32-1. However, I have a another implementation (which I'll have to clean up to publish) that uses lists of BigInteger that could grow as much as your memory allows you too, AFAICT (at the expense of being slower... will modify Atkin sieve to use BigInteger as well to see how they fare against each other.... might throw in Wheel Sieve).

Comment: After translating (probably lousily) the java code into C and comparing with Bernstein's.... my algorithm is _no_ match for Bernstein.... at least not right now (and not for large numbers of primes). At 1e5 numbers, my algorithm is 10x faster than Atkin... but for 1e6 Atkin barely moved and mine is already taking twice the time. For 1e7 it's 10x (ouch!). For 1e8 it's almost 20x (OUCH!) Evaluating possibilities of improvement... but feels like an uphill battle. Will keep you posted if I make **amazing** progress.

Comment: the github link is not available, can you provide it please here?

Comment: Given that my algorithm was no match (up to the point that I could test) to Bernstein's, I took it down probably.